# Регулярное выражение пароля

Tags: регулярные-выражения, валидация, пароль

Как составить регулярку для проверки пароля который должен состоять из

- 2-4 заглавных букв `[A-Z]`,
- 2-4 строчных `[a-z]` и
- 2-4 цифры `\d`, порядок которых может быть разный.

Пример:

```
BPY49io
```

Вот так выглядит моё выражение, которое не работает:

```js
^(?=[A-Z]{2,4})(?=[a-z]{2,4})(?=\d{2,4})$
```

Comment: `(?=([A-Z].*){2,4})` и аналогично

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте

```js
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)[A-Za-z\d]+$
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/SILGt8/1/).

Если в пароле разрешены любые символы, замените `[A-Za-z\d]` на `.`:

```js
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$).+$
```

Если в пароле не должно быть пробельных символов, вместо `[A-Za-z\d]` и `.` надо использовать `\S`:

```js
^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)\S+$
```

И ещё один аспект: если необходимо ограничить длину пароля, вместо `+` в конце используйте

- `{8}` - ровно восемь символов, не более и не менее
- `{8,}` - восемь и более символов
- `{8,30}` - от восьми до тридцати символов.

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует того, чтобы сразу после текущей позиции было 2, 3 или 4 повтора последовательности 0 и более символов, отличных от `A-Z`, за которыми следует заглавная буква, а потом 0 и более символов, отличных от `A-Z до конца строки (т.е. "необходимо наличие двух, трёх или четырёх (но не более) заглавных букв")
- `(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)` - аналогично вышеописанному шаблону, "необходимо наличие двух, трёх или четырёх (но не более) строчных букв"
- `(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)`  - аналогично вышеописанному шаблону, "необходимо наличие двух, трёх или четырёх (но не более) цифр" (`\D` находит любой символ, отличный от цифры)
- `[A-Za-z\d]+` - одна и более букв или цифр
- `.+` - один и более любых символов, отличных от символов перевода строки
- `\S+` - один и более пробельных символов
- `$` - конец строки.

**Примеры использования**:

- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - `/^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)[A-Za-z\d]+$/.test(string)`
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) - `preg_match('/^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)[A-Za-z\d]+$/D', $mystring)`
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) - `Regex.IsMatch(mystring, @"^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*\z)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*\z)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*\z)[A-Za-z\d]+\z")`
- [java](/questions/tagged/java) - `mystring.matches("(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*\\z)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*\\z)(?=(?:\\D*\\d){2,4}\\D*\\z)[A-Za-z\\d]+")`
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `re.fullmatch(r'(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*\Z)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*\Z)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*\Z)[A-Za-z\d]+', mystring)`
- [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) - `/\A(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*\z)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*\z)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*\z)[A-Za-z\d]+\z/.match?(string)`
- [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) - `$mystring -cmatch '^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)[A-Za-z\d]+\z'`
- [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) - `if password.range(of: #"^(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2,4}[^A-Z]*$)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2,4}[^a-z]*$)(?=(?:\D*\d){2,4}\D*$)[A-Za-z\d]+\z"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil { print(true) }`

Comment: Спасибо! ty so much